# Finding expectation with given PDF of $f(x)=2xe^{-x^2}$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, expected-value

> A random variable has PDF given by $f(x)=2xe^{-x^2}$. Derive the expectation of $x$.

Everytime I integrate this for expectation I am getting nowhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could write what the issue is.  Also perhaps you can give the full PDF function for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and, first, verify it integrates to 1.  Wolfram-alpha is useful to quickly get answers.

Comment: I dont know if I phrased the question correctly. I was given the cdf F(x)=1-e^(-x^2);-∞ ≤x<0, when i differentiated it to get the pdf i got f(x)=2xe^(-x^2). Then ive been asked to find the expecation of X. To do that ive used ∫xf(x) dx. When i integrate by parts im being caught in a loop of the same integration. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A CDF needs to be defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Also, your CDF $F(x)$ does not make sense since it satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} F(x)=1$ (but all CDFs should have this limit equal to 0).

Comment: Sorry I read the wrong limits, it should be 0≤x< ∞ For the cdf

Comment: Perhaps you can first integrate the PDF to see if it is 1.  It is also useful since it will likely help you recognize an integral that can be used in the integration by parts for $E[X]$. There are no loops that I can see.

Comment: When i integrated the pdf i got 1. Can i use different limits for the intrgration instead of 0 and infinity?

Comment: Any random variable with a pdf $f(x)$ has an expectation $\int_{-\infty}^{infty} f(x)dx$.  This assumes only that the cdf $F(x)$ has derivative $f(x)$.  The integration limits may be truncated where $f(x)=0$, but nowhere else.

Comment: @user1084631 By integrating the PDF you realize you can find an antiderivative of $2xe^{-x^2}$ (as a function of $x$).  Now that antiderivative will be very useful in the integration by parts formula for $$\int_0^{\infty} \underbrace{x}_{u}\underbrace{(2xe^{-x^2})dx}_{dv}$$

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle \int \limits _0^\infty 2x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx$. We calculate $\displaystyle \int \limits _0^\infty 2x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx$. Set $x^2=y$, $x=\sqrt{y}$ and $dx=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\,dy$. Then the integral becomes:$$\int \limits _0^\infty \sqrt{y}e^y\,dy=\Gamma \left (\frac{3}{2}\right )=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},$$which is the expectation of $f(x)$.

Comment: Correct, as per the $\sigma=1/\sqrt{2}$ case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).

Comment: I didn't know that post! I proved it directly!

Comment: Of course; it was just a sanity check, plus it never hurts to name a distribution.